# Mobiscroll - Selected Item Index

Tags: select, indexing, mobiscroll

How would I get the index of the selected Mobiscroll Item? I am using the 'select' option.  onClose calls `function(valueText, btn, inst)` and onChange calls `function(valueText, inst)`. I can get the 'display' text, button, inst, etc., but not the index of the selected item.

On the Scroller I am displaying the file names in a formatted manner. I need to use the index to get the correct filename from an array. How do I get the index? :-)

Any suggestions?

Thanks a ton.
M&M

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? It is better to include the relevant code in code blocks than trying to describe it in words.

Comment: Well I could use one of these Mobiscroll functions: onSelect : function(valueText, inst)    OR  onChange:function(valueText, inst)  OR onClose: function(valueText, btn, inst) But how do I get the "index" of the selected item rather than the text? This is because my display text is different from actual value of the item.

Comment: Ok I found an easy way out. When I am adding items to Mobiscroll, I also populate an array with the same values. Then all I need to do is "var selected_index = myArray.indexOf(valueText);" and I can get the index of the selected item. The first item index will be a 0. And I can use this in both onClose as well as onSelect events of Mobiscroll. Thanks a ton anyways guys!

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Ok sure thanks...I am a newbie to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found an easy way out. When I am adding items to Mobiscroll, I also populate an array with the same values. Then all I need to do is "var selected_index = myArray.indexOf(valueText);" and I can get the index of the selected item. The first item index will be a 0. And I can use this in both onClose as well as onSelect events of Mobiscroll. Thanks a ton anyways guys!